# Error:C2679 binary '==': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have written my code for an employee management system that stores Employee class objects into a vector, I am getting no errors until I try and compile, I am getting the error: C2679 binary '==': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion). But I am not sure why any help would be great, Thank you!

```
// Employee Management System
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Employee
{
public:
    Employee();
    string GetName();
    string GetStatus();
    float GetSalary();
    int GetAge();
    int GetYearHired();

private:
    string m_Name;
    string m_Status;
    float m_Salary;
    int m_Age;
    int m_YearHired;
};

Employee::Employee()
{
    m_Salary = 0;
    m_Age = 0;
    m_YearHired = 0;
}

string Employee::GetName()
{
    string fName;
    string lName;
    cout << "Please enter the new employee's first name: ";
    cin >> fName;
    cout << "Please enter the new employee's last name: ";
    cin >> lName;
    m_Name = fName + lName;
    return m_Name;
}

string Employee::GetStatus()
{
    string status;
    cout
            << "Please enter the employee's status (full time, part time, or manager): ";
    cin >> status;
    return m_Status;
}

float Employee::GetSalary()
{
    float salary;
    cout << "Please enter the employee's salary: ";
    cin >> salary;
    return m_Salary;
}

int Employee::GetAge()
{
    int age;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the employee's age: ";
        cin >> age;
        if (age > 0)
            break;
        else
            cout << "Error: Please enter a positive value.";
    }
    return m_Age;
}

int Employee::GetYearHired()
{
    int yearHired;
    cout << "Please enter what year the employee was hired: ";
    cin >> yearHired;
    return m_YearHired;
}

class Staff
{
    vector<Employee*> emps;
    vector<Employee*>::const_iterator iter;

public:
    Staff();
    virtual ~Staff();
    void Add();
    void Remove();
    void Clear();
    void Display();
};

Staff::Staff()
{
    emps.reserve(20);
}

Staff::~Staff()
{
    Clear();
}

void Staff::Add()
{
    Employee* emp = new Employee;
    emp->GetName();
    emp->GetStatus();
    emp->GetSalary();
    emp->GetAge();
    emp->GetYearHired();
    emps.push_back(emp);
}

void Staff::Remove()
{
    Employee* emp;
    cout << "Which employee would you like to remove?";
    emp->GetName();

    iter = find(emps.begin(), emps.end(), emp->GetName()); // Trying to find the employee in the datbase.
    if (iter != emps.end()) // If the employee is found in the vector it is removed.
    {
        cout << "\n" << *iter << " was removed\n\n";
        emps.erase(iter); // removes employee from the vector.
    }
    else // If the employee is not found in the vector, it tells the user that the employee was not found.
    {
        cout << "Employee not found, please choose anoter employee.\n\n";
    }
}

void Staff::Clear()
{
    cout << "\nDo you really want to clear all employees? (yes/no)\n"; // Asking the user if they want to clear the database.
    string response;
// Storing the response of the user.
    cin >> response; // Getting the users response (yes/no).
    if (response == "yes") // If response is yes.
    {
        vector<Employee*>::iterator iter = emps.begin(); // Declares an iterator for the emps vector and sets it to the beginning of the vector.
        for (iter = emps.begin(); iter != emps.end(); ++iter) // Iterates through vector.
        {
            delete *iter; // Deletes the iterators in the vector, freeing all memory on the heap.* iter = 0;
            // Sets iterator to zero so it does not become a dangling pointer.
        }
        emps.clear(); // Clear vector of pointers.
    }
    else // If response is no.
    {
        cout << "\nAll employee's remain in the database.\n";
    }
}

void Staff::Display()
{
    Employee* emp;
    if (emps.size() == 0) // Checking to see if the database is empty.
        cout
                << "\nThere are no employee's in the database, add employee's to view them here.\n ";
    else // If the cart contains any items.
    {
        cout << "\nThe database contains: \n";
        for (iter = emps.begin(); iter != emps.end(); ++iter) // Displaying the inventory.
        {
            cout << "-------------------------------------------------";
            cout << "Employee's Name         : " << emp->GetName() << endl;
            cout << "Employee's Status       : " << emp->GetStatus() << endl;
            cout << "Employee's Salary       : " << emp->GetSalary() << endl;
            cout << "Employee's Age          : " << emp->GetAge() << endl;
            cout << "Year employee was hired : " << emp->GetYearHired() << endl;
            cout << "-------------------------------------------------";
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int option = 0;
    Staff stf;
// Welcoming the user to the Employee Management System program.
    cout
            << "Welcome to our Employee Management System! To get started see the menu options below :\n ";

// Main loop
    while (option != 5) // The loop will repeat until the user enters 5 as the option.
    {
        cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- - ";
        cout << "\nMenu Options: \n";
        cout << "\nTo select an option, please type in the number that corresponds to that option.\n ";
        cout << "1 - Add an Employee\n2 - Remove an Employee\n3 - Clear the database\n4 - Display Employee's in Database\n5 - Quit" << endl;
        cout << "\nWhat would you like to do? ";
        cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- - ";

// Start of the validity check.
        bool validInput = false;

        while (!validInput) // The loop will repeat until the users input is valid.
        {
            cin >> option; // User inputs first option choice.
            validInput = true; // Assign the input as valid.
            if (cin.fail()) // Tests to make sure the value assigned is valid for the variable type.
            {
                cout << "\nPlease choose a menu option by number\n";
                cin.clear(); // Clears stream error.
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // Removes an invalid characters.
                validInput = false; // Sets the input back to false, repeats the loop.
            }
        }

        switch (option)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                stf.Add();
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                stf.Remove();
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                stf.Clear();
                break;
            }
            case 4:
            {
                stf.Display();
                break;
            }
            case 5: // If option = 5.
                cout << "\nThank you for using the Employee Management Program!\n";
                // Thanks the user for using the Employee Management program.
                break;
            default: // If the user does not put in a valid option, it tells them to try again.
                cout << "\nThat's not a valid option. Please try again.\n";
                break;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So which line gives the error?  Also, you don't need mountains of code to duplicate a compiler error.

Comment: Code needs a simple edit where `response` is declared, can't do the edit myself because it's less then the minimum number of characters.

Comment: You need an == operator that compares `Employee`s based on their names.

Comment: By the way, whatever you used to format this code, never use it again.

Comment: `iter = find(emps.begin(), emps.end(), emp->GetName());` -- Use `std::find_if`, not `std::find`.  Also, if that's the issue, you could have written a 3 line `main` program that duplicates the error, and not post mountains of code.

Comment: Is this a typo or some arcanery I don't know about? `string fName\` string lName;`

Comment: `Employee* emp; cout << "Which employee would you like to remove?"; emp->GetName();` -- The `emp` is uninitialized.  What name were you expecting to get out of an uninitialized pointer?

Comment: Almost certainly typo.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I do have the response declared as a string but when I tried to paste the code here it got all butchered, sorry about that. This is my first time posting.

Comment: @Jcarlson93 [Same error, less code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98c7cdf5046de7d4).  Almost all (maybe all) compiler errors can be duplicated with a minimum amount of code.

Comment: I did not know where the error was coming from, it only told me the error code posted in the title.

Comment: @Jcarlson93 Going by that error, you are using Visual Studio.  I know that Visual Studio points you to the line that causes the error by just clicking on that error in the error window.

Answer (score 2):

## Problem

`std::find` is going to compare the `Employee *`s in `emps` against the `std::string` that is returned by `GetName`. There is no comparison operator defined for `Employee *` that does this. We can make one, but because the behaviour of `GetName` is to Get and name for the user, not simply return the `Employee`'s name this will quickly become a mess.

## Solution

First Stop storing pointers to `Employee`s in the `vector`s. This simple change will eliminate the vast majority of your past, present and future pain. In general, use `new` as little as possible ([Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)) and when you do find yourself needing `new`, [prefer a smart pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30143936/4581301).

```
vector<Employee*> emps;
```

becomes

```
vector<Employee> emps;
```

that has a ripple effect through your code, not the least of which is

```
void Staff::Add()
{
    Employee* emp = new Employee;
    emp->GetName();
    emp->GetStatus();
    emp->GetSalary();
    emp->GetAge();
    emp->GetYearHired();
    emps.push_back(emp);
}
```

must become

```
void Staff::Add()
{
    Employee emp;
    emp.GetName();
    emp.GetStatus();
    emp.GetSalary();
    emp.GetAge();
    emp.GetYearHired();
    emps.push_back(emp);
}
```

But also look into `emplace_back` and strongly consider getting the user input and then constructing `emp` around it.

```
bool operator==(const Employee & rhs) const
{
    return m_Name == rhs.m_Name;
}
```

or a `friend` function

```
bool operator==(const Employee & lhs,
                const Employee & rhs)
{
    return lhs.m_Name == rhs.m_Name;
}
```

and then change the call to `find` to compare `Employee`s

```
iter = find(emps.begin(), emps.end(), emp); // Trying to find the employee in the datbase.
```

This may lead to more problems because `iter` is a `const_iterator` and a member variable ([Rubber Ducky wants a word with you about this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)). Also completely ignores the fact that there are a few dozen more logical mistakes in the the code.

Comment: @ user4581301 So would I need to make my `const_iterator` just a plain `iterator`?

Comment: Compile it and find out.

Comment: @user4581301 There is no need to add an `operator ==` if `std::find_if` were used instead of `std::find`.

Comment: I made the changes to `emps` vector to `vector<Employee> emps;` and changed the `std::find` but now I am getting an error for `cout << "\n" << iter << " was removed\n\n";` on the `<<` right after `"\n"` but the last set is not throwing any errors

Comment: @user4581301 the error I am getting is no operator "<<" matches these operands.

Comment: Like I said, there are a lot of errors in your code.  C++ has no mechanism for knowing how to print out custom classes you devise, let alone iterators  that reference them. You will have to add a `operator<<` that knows how to print an `Employee` and dereference the iterator.  A write up on that and operators in general can be found here: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me (EDIT: had a commented out) `string response;` declaration before

```
cin >> response; // Getting the users response (yes/no).
```

Hope this points you in the right direction

EDIT:
It's there but it's commented out. Try:

```
cout << "\nDo you really want to clear all employees? (yes/no)\n"; 
// Asking the user if they want to clear the database.
string response;
// Storing the response of the user.
cin >> response; // Getting the users response (yes/no).
if (response == "yes") // If response is yes.
```

And I'd double check all the code to avoid the comments interfering with the code

Comment: No they didn't. It's there. Whatever the asker used to format their code chewed it up and slapped some lines of code in with comments on previous lines.

Comment: See the line above, it's a layout problem.

Comment: If you use CTRL+F, I could not locate any instance of the word "response" earlier than `cin >> response;` that wasn't commented out. But yeah, the problem is the commenting, and I'm not sure exactly why OP didn't notice that to begin with. Perhaps using a "code formatter in c++" would help

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/g/nWydYL) is a link with the code properly formatted, probably how OP has it in their IDE. Im guessing whoever pasted it on here had word wrapping enabled.